# Externally linking xml with different css files

Tags: html, css, xml

I have one xml file. I want to format it using different css files. 
For example: I click one button on html page which displays x.xml file with a.css style, I click different button, it displays same x.xml file but with different style (let say b.css).

Something like this wont work:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="a.css" ?>
```

I know I can do this with .xsl and .php

Is it possible to do this with css on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

How about using same .css file and adding 2 diffrent button styles, then you can use JS to change the styles from 1 .css.

Comment: How to change xml style with Javascript?